# Changing a UITextView when a UITableView cell is touched

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

This seems like a simple question but I just can't find the answer.

I just want to change the text in a uitextview when the user touches a cell in a uitableview.

What the uitextview will change to will depend on what cell they click in the table.

This is what i am trying:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    myTextView.text = [myData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I have tested out to make sure myTextView is working fine by initialising it in ViewDidLoad and the text goes in fine.

Also as a backstory... there is a table with data from an array called myArray... when you touch one of the cells, it goes to another screen with pretty much just a UITextView which will then read from another array myArray2 with the row number from what you clicked to the corresponding row from the array.

When i do all of this the text just does NOT change.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's myData2? What does it contain?

Comment: does text change when you did myTextView.text = @"foo";

Comment: myData and myData2 are just arrays of strings

Comment: and no nothing changes at all...

Comment: It would help to see a little more data, per screen / class preferably. It could be anything that happens outside these 2 lines.

Comment: Everything else seems to be working fine... As in I can change the text in ViewDidLoad and it works just fine. It just seems to be this didSelectRowAtIndexPath thing.

Comment: get didSelectRowAtIndexPath called?! else set self.tableView.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

is myTextView a (IBOutlet) property? And if so, is it actually linked to the actual IB object in Inerface Builder as an outlet? It sounds like something is wrong there based on the fact that it also does not change if you put in a simple line to change the code (as seen in the comments)

Comment: Yes i declared like this: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

Comment: and the outlet for the UITextView in the Storyboard is the View Controller.

Comment: and is the outlet connected?

Comment: the outlet is a delegate -> View controller

Comment: What do you mean by connected? It has the delegate bubble connected to View controller when i right click on the TextView in IB

Comment: @user1902893 you need to set the referencing outlet as well, to the proerty that you declared. Not just the delegate. The referencing outlet for the textView in the nib should be connected to the File's Owner / myTextField

Comment: in IB right click on your UITextView, then under referencing outlets must be a connection to your myTextView instance

Comment: the referencing outlet has (myTextView) -> (View Controller)

Comment: Hmm it still looks as before. (myTextView) -> (View Controller)

Comment: my TableView delegate is set to View Controller also... Shouldnt I usually have all of my delegates set to View Controller?

Comment: You need to set your referencing outlet to myTextView for the UITextView. the delegate should be the viewController, or any other class that handles the methods specific to this TextView.    But as long as you do not connect the outlet you cannot control the IB element from your code, like putting text in it. So take care of that first.

Comment: How would i do that? Everywhere that i drag after clicking the circle to add a new referencing outlet just creates it to view controller. And if this was the case.. wouldnt i not be able to even change the text in ViewDidLoad? Because i can put in a command to change the text to foo in there and it works fine..

Comment: But in an earlier comment you stated that the text did not change... thats what I based this on. If it does change you can disregard all of this.

Comment: It didn't change the text if the call was inside the didSelectRowAtIndex path. If I do it in the ViewDidLoad I am able to change text.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have connected your delegate properly. If you haven't connected your delegate then `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method will not get called.

Comment: It seems from the comment that he cannot reach the TextView from code, which would not be related to the delegate of the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

from what you have written in your question,i think you textview is in another controller, so first of all, you can not update UI of some controller from another controller directly. you have to make a int type property in view controller containing textview, set that int as the indexPath.row. and use that int as objectAtIndex for myData2 array. you ave to do some work if your textView is really in another view controller